# Need help with custom init script

Tags: redhat, init

I'm trying to set up an init script for a process on redhat linux:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Startup script for Conquest
#
# chkconfig: 345 85 15     - start or stop process definition within the boot process
# description: Conquest DICOM Server
# processname: conquest
# pidfile: /var/run/conquest.pid

# Source function library.      This creates the operating environment for the process to be started
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

CONQ_DIR=/usr/local/conquest

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting Conquest DICOM server: "
        cd $CONQ_DIR && daemon --user mruser ./dgate -v                 - Starts only one process of a given name.
        echo
        touch /var/lock/subsys/conquest
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down Conquest DICOM server: "
        killproc conquest
        echo
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/conquest
        rm -f /var/run/conquest.pid      - Only if process generates this file
        ;;
  status)
        status conquest
        ;;
  restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
  reload)
        echo -n "Reloading process-name: "
        killproc conquest -HUP
        echo
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

However, the `cd $CONQ_DIR` is getting ignored, because the script errors out:

```
# ./conquest start
Starting Conquest DICOM server: -bash: ./dgate: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

For some reason, I have to run dgate as ./dgate.  I cannot specify the full path `/usr/local/conquest/dgate`

The software came with an init script for a Debian system, so the script uses `start-stop-daemon`, with the option `--chdir` to where dgate is, but I haven't found a way to do this with the Redhat daemon function.

Comment: Perhaps dgate is a script, and you can fix that so it can be run from the full path?

Comment: No, it's a binary.

Comment: Have you been able to run the process without an init script, and then in another terminal verify the process is running with ps?  I don't see confirmation of it working outside of the init in this discussion.

Comment: Yes, it does work if I run it manually.  `ps -aux | grep dgate` shows a ./dgate process running.

Comment: Is it possible that it's running as "conquest", not "dgate"?  I ask because the stop is doing `killproc conquest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
daemon --user mruser ${CONQ_DIR}/dgate -v
```

?

Edit:

```
cd ${CONQ_DIR} && daemon --user mruser ./dgate -v &
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  For some reason, I have to run dgate as ./dgate. I cannot specify the full path /usr/local/conquest/dgate

Comment: Can you add a "echo $CONQ_DIR" before the "cd $CONQ_DIR && daemon --user mruser ./dgate -v" line and let me know what it says?

Comment: It says `Starting Conquest DICOM server: /usr/local/conquest`.

Comment: Ok, so it's getting the path...  Is there a "conquest" running?  How about any processes running as "mruser" ?

Comment: No, nothing... the script halts after echoing /usr/local/conquest and just sits there.  I have to ctrl+c to kill it.

Comment: See my updated comment.  Try that.

Comment: Doing that gives:

Starting Conquest DICOM server: /usr/local/conquest
./dgate: No such file or directory

Comment: adding the "&" to the end of your line makes it error with "No such file or directory" ? `cd $CONQ_DIR && daemon --user mruser ./dgate -v &` ?  I hope the `${}` didn't give it problems.

Answer (score 2):

Old question is old, still: you can troubleshoot this kind of problem with a `set -x` (xtrace) at the top of your script. Also, consider `set -e`, so the script errors out early.

Answer (score 0):

Does dgate file has execution permission?

Try to echo the current directory (echo `pwd`) before launch dgate.

Regards,
Lorenzo.

Comment: Yes, dgate is executable.  I can run it manually.  `echo pwd` shows the CD command is working, but `./dgate` just doesn't work.  If I add `$CONQ_DIR/dgate`, then do `/etc/init.d/conquest start`, it says it starts OK, but `ps ax` shows no dgate process running.

Comment: Try to replace:

 cd $CONQ_DIR && daemon --user mruser ./dgate -v

with:

cd $CONQ_DIR && sudo -u mruser ./dgate -v

Comment: I did this... now for some reason the script stops responding at "Starting Conquest DICOM server:".  I even tried to change it back to the previous "daemon" line, but it still halts.  What would make an init script halt?

Answer (score 0):

export CONQ_DIR
The subshell doesn't know about the directory.

e.g.

```
$ FOO=skhfkjsdh
$ cat foo.sh

    echo $FOO

$ sh foo.sh

$ export FOO=skhfkjsdh
$ sh foo.sh
skhfkjsdh
$
```

Comment: I think it does... see my comment on lg's Answer.